# search from two tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have two tables I want to create a search query where I search in both tables using regular expressions, here is my query I want to search in

```
SELECT artikel_id as id, artikel_overskrift as overskrift, artikel_keywords as keywords, artikel_text as texten FROM artikler
UNION ALL
SELECT begivenheder_id as id, begivenheder_title as overskrift, begivenheder_keyword as keywords, begivenheder_beskrivelse as texten FROM begivenheder
```

How can in order and sort this query

Comment: In what way do you want to sort the table?  Have you tried anything?  What was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what stops you from using this query as a sub-query and applying an order by clause over it?

If this is not what you want then please elaborate your issue. example

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT artikel_id as id, artikel_overskrift as overskrift, artikel_keywords as keywords,     artikel_text as texten FROM artikler
UNION ALL
SELECT begivenheder_id as id, begivenheder_title as overskrift, begivenheder_keyword as keywords, begivenheder_beskrivelse as texten FROM begivenheder
 )TAB1 ORDER BY ID
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this even needs a sub-select.

The following should order the whole result set by the overskrift column:

```
SELECT artikel_id as id, artikel_overskrift as overskrift, artikel_keywords as keywords, artikel_text as texten
FROM artikler
UNION ALL
SELECT begivenheder_id as id, begivenheder_title as overskrift, begivenheder_keyword as keywords, begivenheder_beskrivelse as texten
FROM begivenheder
ORDER BY overskrift
```